# Determining the best initial values for nls function in rstudio

Tags: r, nls

I am working on my thesis problem with this given data set :

```
x<- cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))
y <- cbind(c(0.37, 0.25, 0.23, 0.24, 0.32, 0.23, 0.24, 0.26, 0.24, 0.26, 0.27, 0.27))

df <- data.frame('x' = x, 'y' = y)
```

I want to fit with these two models y = a + exp(b + (c*x)). I asked chat GPT and the answer confused me. It told me to try to perform a linear regression with data df, and use intercept as starting value a and x as starting value b.

How is actually the right way or the best way to determine the initial values in nls? especially with my data and model?

I tried to perform a linear regression with data df, and use intercept as starting value a and x as starting value b. And for starting values c assumed to be equal with b.

```
m1 <- nls(y ~ model_func1(x, a, b, c), data = df , start = list(a = -0.003033, b=0.284778, c=0.284778), trace = T)
summary(m1)
```

But I always encountered this error

```
Error in nls(y ~ model_func1(x, a, b, c), data = df,  : 
  singular gradient
```

Comment: In your model `a`and `b` are linearly dependent, that's why you get an error. To see why, set x=0 and y=0, then you have `0=a+exp(b)`. This means that you can find for any value of a a suitable value of b to fulfill the equation. Could you also post your `model_func1()` code?

Comment: For any value of b there is exists a suitable value of a, not the other way round. For a>0 there is no suitable value of b

Comment: `x` has 13 data points, `y` has only 12. This is an error.

Comment: @Maultasche I don't think model coefficients can be linearly dependent and I find your reasoning difficult to follow. To me the equation seems perfectly fine and fittable. We do need to see the full code, though.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments x and y have different lengths so the data.frame(...) statement will not work.  Also we do not need `cbind`.  Assuming that the `x` definition is the one that is wrong use the input definition shown below.  The starting values used in the question would work but using starting values of 1 for each parameter also works so let us use that.  (The starting values in the question are slightly better since they result in convergence after 26 iterations vs 29 for all 1's but all 1's seems simpler.)  Although this results in convergence the plot shows it does not fit the first point well so we try the `lm` model shown and note that it fits easily and has a lower deviance (= residual sum of squares) and only requires 2 parameters rather than 3 in the original model.

```
# input
y <- c(0.37, 0.25, 0.23, 0.24, 0.32, 0.23, 0.24, 0.26, 0.24, 0.26, 0.27, 0.27)
df <- data.frame(x = seq_along(y), y)

fo <- y ~ a + exp(b + c * x)
st <- list(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1)
fm <- nls(fo, df, start = st)
deviance(fm)
## [1] 0.01866574
```

By trial and error we find this model which has better deviance, i.e. lower residual sum of squares, i.e. 0.008170078 vs. 0.01866574 and also looks more reasonable in the plot shown at the end.

```
# alternate model
fm2 <- lm(y ~ I(1/x^2), df)
deviance(fm2)
## [1] 0.008170078

# graphics
plot(df)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, df, col = "red")
lines(fitted(fm2) ~ x, df, col = "blue")
legend("topright", c("fm", "fm2"), lty = 1, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much for your previous answer! it's very useful for me. But unfortunately when I try to run the program, I still encountered this error 

Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env, central = nDcentral) :
Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

I use rstudio Version 2023.03.0+386 in macbook